# Filter over IEnumerable ... .Where?

Tags: c#, generator, ienumerable

I made a function to generate the odd numbers:

```
static IEnumerable<int> OddNumbers()
{
  int n = 1;
  while (true)
    yield return 1 + 2 * (n++ - 1);
}
```

How do I go through and filter this list? I am trying to remove all the multiples of a certain number `factor`, I wrote this:

```
using (var oddNumbers = OddNumbers().GetEnumerator())
{
  oddNumbers.MoveNext();
  int factor = oddNumbers.Current;

  yield return factor;
  oddNumbers = oddNumbers.Where(x => x % factor != 0);
}
```

but I get told that

```
The type arguments for method `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(
  this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>,
  System.Func<TSource,bool>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`
```

Comment: Declare `oddNumbers` as: `IEnumerable<int> oddNumbers=OddNumbers();`. Then use another variable in the `using` for the enumerator.

Comment: `oddNumbers` is an `IEnumerator<int>` but `Where` requires an `IEnumerable<int>`. You can just use `OddNumbers().Where(x => x % factor != 0)`.

Comment: Uh... all of these operations seem scarily infinite...

Comment: `oddNumbers` is an _IEnumerator_, though, not an _IEnumerable_. I don't see how you could even execute `Where` on it.

Comment: Would be good if you tell us the whole problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Evk generating all the lucky numbers

Comment: @Nyerguds C# should be able to handle a filter over an infinite enumerator right? Like every other decent language?

Comment: I'm thinking it might be easier to use the "mod" operator to simplify not only generating the odd number array, but also filtering the multiples. For example, to generate the odd array just check if (x % 2 ==1), and that means it's an odd number. Then to, for example, check if the number is a multiple of, say, 6, again use (x % 6 ==0). Then a single method can check if odd or multiples. Just a thought...

Comment: But with lucky numbers you remove every X item in the remaining set, that is not related to divisibility by X (so, not related to x % factor).

Comment: @minseong Ya, I missed the fact the second was _also_ a `yield` function, heh.

Answer (score 3):

To my understanding there is no need to access the enumerator directly, it can be done using Linq alone as follows.

```
var FilteredNumbers = OddNumbers().Where(x => x % factor != 0);
```

Comment: However be sure to apply any guard on the enumerable, e.g. Take(), to prevent infinite loop if later on you iterate through the full collection: foreach, .ToList(). etc...

Comment: I am repeatedly filtering the collection, and would like the next filter to use the output of the previous. Is there a way to filter the collection in-place and store the result? Ready to be filtered again?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use *Linq*:

```
   // Initial generator
   static IEnumerable<int> OddNumbers() {
     for (int n = 1; ; n += 2) // for loop is far better than while here
       yield return n; 
   }  

   ...

   var result = OddNumbers()
     .Where(x => x % factor ! = 0);
```

Or *modify* the generator itself:

```
   static IEnumerable<int> OddNumbersAdvanced(int factorToExclude = int.MinValue) {
     for (int n = 1; ; n += 2)
       if (n % factorToExclude != 0) 
          yield return n;  
   }  

   ...

   var result = OddNumbersAdvanced(factor);
```

To go through use `foreach` loop:

```
  foreach (int item in result) {
    //TODO: put relevant code here; do not forget to break the loop
  }
```

Comment: I am repeatedly filtering the collection, and would like the next filter to use the output of the previous. Is there a way to filter the collection  in-place and store the result? Ready to be filtered again?

Comment: You can *stack up* the filters: `var result = OddNumbers().Where(item => item % factor ! = 0).Where(item => item < 100000).Where(item => (item * item) % 5 == 1);` just put as many `Where` are required

Comment: @minseong: the `OddNumbers()` generator returns infinitely many items, so *beware* simple solutions like `.ToList()`. Put `TakeWhile()` or `Take()` before `.ToList()`

Comment: I never want a list. I am not trying to use it as a list. But thanks.

Comment: @minseong: I see; I've just read "How do I go through and filter this list". Inifinitely many *items* are OK (with some restrictions, e.g. you can't put `OrderBy`, `ToList()` etc.), infinitely many *filters* are not (unless they are *not arbitrary* filters).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128357/discussion-between-dmitry-bychenko-and-theonlygusti).

Answer (score 0):

Since you need that to generate sequence of lucky numbers, here is some code I wrote to do this with iterators. Note that it's very inefficient to do that this way, but hopefully you are doing this just for fun or for learning

```
static IEnumerable<int> LuckyNumbers(IEnumerable<int> all = null, int n = 2, int step = 0) {
    if (step == 0) {
        all = Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue); // start with all numbers
        yield return 1;
        step++;
    }            
    // apply a filter for current "n" (starting with 2)
   var filtered = Filtered(all, n);
   // get next item from the sequence (skip items first, because this sequence represents whole lucky number sequence, starting from 1)
    var current = filtered.Skip(step).First();
    yield return current;
    step++;
    // now recursive call back into LuckyNumber
    foreach (var other in LuckyNumbers(filtered, current, step)) {
        yield return other;
    }
}

static IEnumerable<int> Filtered(IEnumerable<int> previous, int n) {
    // filter out each n-th item
    return previous.Where((x, i) => (i + 1)%n != 0);
}
```

Use like this:

```
foreach (var next in LuckyNumbers().Take(10)) {
    Console.WriteLine(next);
}
```

Comment: You tell me "that is not related to divisibility by X (so, not related to x % factor)" yet I see in your own answer: ".Where((x, i) => (i + 1)%n != 0);"

Comment: @minseong Well in my answer I divide not x, but i (index of the  item in a sequence, not number itself).

Comment: I do this in my most current solution. I made a mistake in the question.